# New Flutter App fails when adding dependency cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I followed these steps to create a new flutter app and add cloud_firestore dependency

1. I setup flutter on my MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3
2. I typed in command line: `flutter create test_dependencies`
3. `dart migrate --apply-changes`
4. `flutter run`
   -> The app works fine as a web app. The chrome browsers opens up the app and I can use the counter
5. I run `flutter pub add cloud_firestore`
6. I confirmed that cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7 was added in pubspec.yaml
7. I then updated all dependencies and index.html as shown below
8. I run `flutter packages get`
9. I run `flutter run`

Now I get this error. I actually had a larger app and I started with this simple scenario to isolate the problem. This is the simplest app I can write and it still fails. Any help will be appreciated.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
> at Object.app$ [as app] (http://localhost:64162/packages/firebase_core_web/src/interop/core.dart.lib.js:42:101)
> at new cloud_firestore_web.FirebaseFirestoreWeb.new (http://localhost:64162/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:865:64)
> at Function.registerWith (http://localhost:64162/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:788:73)
> at Object.registerPlugins (http://localhost:64162/packages/blackdoor/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js:33:46)
> at main (http://localhost:64162/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:41:35)
> at main.next ()
> at runBody (http://localhost:64162/dart_sdk.js:37228:34)
> at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:64162/dart_sdk.js:37259:7)
> at main$ (http://localhost:64162/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:40:18)
> at http://localhost:64162/main_module.bootstrap.js:19:10
> at Array.forEach ()
> at window.$dartRunMain (http://localhost:64162/main_module.bootstrap.js:18:32)
> at :1:8
> at Object.runMain (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8656:21)
> at http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22068:19
> at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3830:15)
> at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:10905:12)
> at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3794:20)
> at main__closure1.$call$body$main__closure (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22080:16)
> at main__closure1.call$1 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22007:19)
> at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary [as call$2$5] (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4153:16)
> at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12136:39)
> at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12068:14)
> at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11697:19)
> at _DelayedData.perform$1 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11849:59)
> at _PendingEvents_schedule_closure.call$0 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11898:14)
> at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3990:24)
> at StaticClosure._startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3996:11)
> at _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1 (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:10774:9)
> at invokeClosure (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1250:26)
> at MutationObserver. (http://localhost:64162/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1269:18)

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.
    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.
    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="An apiro project.">
  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="blackdoor">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <title>blackdoor</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=1463819943');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "***"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***pubspec.yaml***

```
name: blackdoor
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: 
    sdk: flutter         
  provider: ^5.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  http: ^0.13.1
  image_picker: ^0.7.4

  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7
  cloud_firestore_web: ^1.0.7
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.2
  firebase_auth_web: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core_web: ^1.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3
  firebase_messaging_web: ^1.0.6
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.5
  firebase_storage_web: ^1.0.5

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  generate: true # Enable generate flag for localisation  

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700

    - family: Quicksand
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Adding this at the bottom of android/app/build.gradle solved the problem temporarily for me, maybe it will work for you too:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`

Comment: The error log you posted is most likely generated by building the web version of flutter, not Android or iOS. Because you would be seeing a platform exception then. Can you double check? It's also because probably you have an auto generated webpluginregistrant.dart file, and it's missing some core web dependencies.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad yes you are correct I am building the web version of flutter. I don't know what dependencies I need to add

Comment: Checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843752/typeerror-cannot-read-property-app-of-undefined-error-flutter-using-firebas) , if it doesn't solve the problem, please share your pubspec.yaml and index.html and we can figure it out.

Comment: Can you please the index.html and pubspec.yaml as an addition to your question, you can edit your post and add the items. It'll be easier to read, without character limits

Comment: It's okay, you can delete them from the comment section, and post them as an adition to your post. Select `edit` and edit the post. Also, check my answer below, it could solve your issue based on the dependencies you posted here.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I used the dependencies you provided and it is still failing. I'll provide index.html and pubspec.yaml and the error. Let me try to troubleshoot it myself first

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I am still getting an error after updating the dependencies. I copied index.html and pubspec.yaml above. It is the same error even if I remove all dependencies and I don't update index.html. Even if I start a completely new project with "flutter create my_project" and then add this as a dependency 

cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7

Comment: Use 8.4.1, not 8.4.3 and try again

Comment: ok something is happening now... I am now getting this message
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined
    at new firebase_messaging_web.FirebaseMessagingWeb.new (http://localhost:50168/packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart.lib.js:169:51)
    at Function.registerWith (http://localhost:50168/packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart.lib.js:61:73)

Comment: I removed these from pubspec.yaml

  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3
  firebase_messaging_web: ^1.0.6

and this from index.html 

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
and I can run it now .... so I just need to find the right versions for messaging

Answer (score 0):

As of May1st, 2021

Add these dependencies to your pubspec.yaml:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7
  cloud_firestore_web: ^1.0.7
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.2
  firebase_auth_web: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core_web: ^1.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3
  firebase_messaging_web: ^1.0.6
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.5
  firebase_storage_web: ^1.0.5
```