# TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined in flutter? and flutter web not working?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

**I  created new flutter project and add cloud firestore  in pubspec.yaml file then after my project is not run on chrome web and show "[+1534 ms] TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined" and remove dependency of cloud firestore then run on web its work perfectly  **

```
pubspec.yaml
name: ra_store
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+1
  firebase_auth: ^1.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  image: ^3.0.2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  intl:
#  cloud_firestore_web: ^2.1.1




# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**How can i solve this bug any one help me**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined Error - Flutter using firebase Auth and Firestore in flutter web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843752/typeerror-cannot-read-property-app-of-undefined-error-flutter-using-firebas)

Answer (score 0):

Move your dependencies under "dependencies".. Not under dev_dependencies. This should fix your issue.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+1
  firebase_auth: ^1.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  image: ^3.0.2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  intl:

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

Comment: Which simulator are you trying to run your app ? is it iOS or android. Because to run iOS you need to set your platform :ios, '10.0' in Podfile, then need to run flutter clean, pod install and few other steps in order to use newest version of firebase services.

Comment: its working on andrid perfectly but its not run on web (Chrome)

Comment: sorry, did not start with web, working only mobiles.. good luck, keep digging.. u will sort it out soon...