# Impossible to run firestore in a webapp

Tags: flutter

I have some issues to run flutter web app simple example after added firestore package and firecore

I have well follow all process

1-creation of firebase account
2-creation of web app
3-copie the javascript generated code

```
 <script type="module">
      // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
    
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "1:..."
      };
    
      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
```

past in the body of  web/index.html

4-I have add firestore and firecore in the pubspec.yaml
5- I have add

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
```

6- I have add

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

But I have this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')
    at Object.app$ [as app] (http://localhost:54144/packages/firebase_core_web/src/interop/core.dart.lib.js:31:101)
    at new cloud_firestore_web.FirebaseFirestoreWeb.new (http://localhost:54144/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:833:64)
    at Function.registerWith (http://localhost:54144/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:745:73)
    at Object.registerPlugins (http://localhost:54144/packages/boxe_ouiquit_web_app/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js:16:46)
    at main (http://localhost:54144/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:31:35)
    at main.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:54144/dart_sdk.js:37422:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:54144/dart_sdk.js:37453:7)
    at main$ (http://localhost:54144/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:30:18)
    at http://localhost:54144/main_module.bootstrap.js:19:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at window.$dartRunMain (http://localhost:54144/main_module.bootstrap.js:18:32)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
    at Object.runMain (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8825:21)
    at http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22713:19
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3851:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11063:12)
    at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3815:20)
    at main__closure1.$call$body$main__closure (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22725:16)
    at main__closure1.call$1 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22652:19)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary [as call$2$5] (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4185:16)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12436:39)
    at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12383:14)
    at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11959:19)
    at _DelayedData.perform$1 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12148:59)
    at _PendingEvents_schedule_closure.call$0 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12197:14)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4023:24)
    at StaticClosure._startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4029:11)
    at _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1 (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:10932:9)
    at invokeClosure (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1259:26)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (http://localhost:54144/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1278:18)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843752/typeerror-cannot-read-property-app-of-undefined-error-flutter-using-firebas/66845141#66845141) answer your question?